# Facet block based on other facet choice

Tags: 7, search

I have a site where search is based on Search API (mysql server). I have two fields in my content type (brand and model) and I have created two faced block based on these fields. They work.

Now I want to make visible the model's facet block only when users have chose the brand (from the faced block).

Is this possible without a custom module or PHP code that searches in `$_GET` the brand chosen from the users?

Answer (score 0):

Better is later than never :)

Try to use "dependencies" from context menu of facet block.